# Behaviour of commas within parentheses in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a twofold question which involves something I would consider to be incorrect Javascript code.

How is the following statement interpreted in Javascript, and why?

```
(1,2,3,4)
```

Why is there a difference between these two invocations:

```
var a = (1,2,3,4);
a();
```

which leads to `a` being equal to `4` and `Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function` being thrown, and

```
(1,2,3,4)();
```

which leads to `Uncaught TypeError: (((1 , 2) , 3) , 4) is not a function`?

Comment: Read more about the comma operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: There is no difference. I get `4 is not a function` in FireFox in both cases..

Comment: Looks like a chromium bug to me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> How is the following statement interpreted in Javascript, and why?
>
> ```
> (1,2,3,4)
> ```

That's a *comma operator* expression (actually, a chain of them) wrapped in grouping parentheses. The comma operator is quite unusual: It evalutes both of its operands, then takes the value of the second one as its value, throwing away the value of the first one. You have a chain of them there, so the value of 1 is evaluated, then 2, then 3, then 4, and the result of the comma operator chain is the value 4; the result of the grouped parentheses expression is therefore 4.

> Why is there a difference between these two invocations:
>
> ```
> var a = (1,2,3,4);
> a();
> ```

Because of the syntax of the language. In the first case, it's clearly not a function call, as there's no value prior to the first `(` to call. The parsing rules for a complex language like JavaScript are just that: Complex. The parser is context-sensitive, and knows how to differentiate between grouping parentheses and function-call parentheses.

> which leads to a being equal to 4 and Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function being thrown, and
>
> ```
> (1,2,3,4)();
> ```
>
> which leads to Uncaught TypeError: (((1 , 2) , 3) , 4) is not a function?

In both cases, the error message is quoting the expression that yielded the result it then tried to call as a function.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the second part of the question. Why is the error message so strange for `(1, 2, 3, 4)()`? If I do something like `(1+2)()`, I get a message saying "3 is not a function", not "(1+2) is not a function". If I do something like `(1+2, 3)()`, I get a message referring to `(3, 3)` instead of `3` or `(1+2, 3)`. It seems like the comma operator evaluation is suspended somehow, or the error message is being produced in a strange way.

Comment: On second thought, if you're just comparing `a()` and `(1, 2, 3, 4)()`, I suppose it does look like the Javascript engine just parsed and deparsed the expression it tried to call. Further experimentation shows a lot of other weird cases in at least Chrome's error messages for bad function calls, so I don't know if it's worth digging too deep in this answer.

Comment: @user2357112 Looking at the [ES6 expression grammar](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-expressions), it looks like any kind of *ShiftExpression* has its evaluated value included in the error message. Any kind of *Expression* that is not a *ShiftExpression* has the parsed, unevaluated text in the error message. Compare `(1 || 2 || 3 || 4)()` versus `(1 + 2 + 3)()` or `(1 << 2)()` (the first is not a kind of `ShiftExpression`, the second two are). This appears to be merely a quirk of Chrome's parser or error reporter.

Answer (score 6):

There is an operator in JS (among other languages) called the comma operator. It simply takes two operands, and returns the rightmost one.

```
a = 1, 2; // a now equals 2
```

It is, however, *not* the same comma as the function parameter separator. It is an operator.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the second part of the question.

Answer (score 4):

> The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

So, the statement `(1,2,3,4);` returns `4`, so `var a = (1,2,3,4);` means that  `a` is equal to `4` which, is not a function, thus the error.

Likewise, `(1,2,3,4)` is just a grouping of comma operators and not a function, thus the second error.

Comment: Although you didn't answer the second question.

Comment: @VisioN Yup, updated. Thanks for keeping me honest :)